# Prove the Cauchy Convergence for Brachystochrone

Tags: analysis, cauchy-sequences

I used Cauchy Criteria to show that there is an Integral for the solution of the Brachistochrone and got $$\Big| \int_{t_{k}}^{b}f(x)dx - \int_{t_{l}}^{b} f(x)dx\Big| = \Big| \int_{t_{k}}^{t_{l}}f(x)dx\Big| = \underbrace{\Big| \int_{t_{k}}^{t_{l}} \tfrac{\sqrt{1+(u'(x))^2}}{\sqrt{u(x)}}dx\Big|}_{(I)}$$
.
I substituted and solved the Integral $$\Big| \int_{\beta_{k}}^{\beta_{l}} \sqrt{\tfrac{1+(y'(x))^2}{y(\beta)}}\tfrac{dx}{d \beta} d \beta\Big| = \Big| \int_{\beta_{k}}^{\beta_{l}} \sqrt{(1 + \tfrac{R^2sin^2(\beta)}{R^2(1-cos(\beta))^2}) \cdot \tfrac{R^2(1-cos(\beta))^2}{R(1-cos(\beta))}} d \beta \Big|$$

and got

$$\Big|\sqrt{\tfrac{R}{g}} (\beta_{l}-\beta_{k})\Big|$$
...
$$\beta_{k} \ and \ \beta_{l}$$

are sequences with $$\beta \in [0,2 \pi)$$ and $$k>l$$

how can I show with the help of

$$\varepsilon>\tfrac{1}{N}$$

that my sequences are converging, so that:

$$\Big|\sqrt{\tfrac{R}{g}} (\beta_{l}-\beta_{k})\Big|<\varepsilon$$